# Unmarshalling `time.Time` from JSON fails when escaping '+' as `\u002b` in files but works in plain strings: cannot parse "\\u002b00:00\"" as "Z07:00"

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm unmarshalling into a struct that has a `time.Time` field named Foo:

```golang
type AStructWithTime struct {
    Foo time.Time `json:"foo"`
}
```

My expectation is, that after unmarshalling I get something like this:

```golang
var expectedStruct = AStructWithTime{
    Foo: time.Date(2022, 9, 26, 21, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
}
```

#### Working Example 1: Plain JSON Objects into Structs

This works fine when working with plain json strings:

```golang
func Test_Unmarshalling_DateTime_From_String(t *testing.T) {
    jsonStrings := []string{
        "{\"foo\": \"2022-09-26T21:00:00Z\"}",           // trailing Z = UTC offset
        "{\"foo\": \"2022-09-26T21:00:00+00:00\"}",      // explicit zero offset
        "{\"foo\": \"2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00\"}", // \u002b is an escaped '+'
    }
    for _, jsonString := range jsonStrings {
        var deserializedStruct AStructWithTime
        err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &deserializedStruct)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("Could not unmarshal '%s': %v", jsonString, err) // doesn't happen
        }
        if deserializedStruct.Foo.Unix() != expectedStruct.Foo.Unix() {
            t.Fatal("Unmarshalling is erroneous") // doesn't happen
        }
        // works; no errors
    }
}
```

#### Working Example 2: JSON Array into Slice

It also works, if I unmarshal the same objects from a json array into a slice:

```golang
func Test_Unmarshalling_DateTime_From_Array(t *testing.T) {
    // these are just the same objects as above, just all in one array instead of as single objects/dicts
    jsonArrayString := "[{\"foo\": \"2022-09-26T21:00:00Z\"},{\"foo\": \"2022-09-26T21:00:00+00:00\"},{\"foo\": \"2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00\"}]"
    var slice []AStructWithTime // and now I need to unmarshal into a slice
    unmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonArrayString), &slice)
    if unmarshalErr != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not unmarshal array: %v", unmarshalErr)
    }
    for index, instance := range slice {
        if instance.Foo.Unix() != expectedStruct.Foo.Unix() {
            t.Fatalf("Unmarshalling failed for index %v: Expected %v but got %v", index, expectedStruct.Foo, instance.Foo)
        }
    }
    // works; no errors
}
```

#### *Not* Working Example

Now I do the same unmarshalling with a JSON read from a file "test.json". Its content is the array from the working example above:

```json
[
  {
    "foo": "2022-09-26T21:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "foo": "2022-09-26T21:00:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    "foo": "2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00"
  }
]
```

The code is:

```golang
func Test_Unmarshalling_DateTime_From_File(t *testing.T) {
    fileName := "test.json"
    fileContent, readErr := os.ReadFile(filepath.FromSlash(fileName))
    if readErr != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not read file %s: %v", fileName, readErr)
    }
    if fileContent == nil {
        t.Fatalf("File %s must not be empty", fileName)
    }
    var slice []AStructWithTime
    unmarshalErr := json.Unmarshal(fileContent, &slice)
    if unmarshalErr != nil {
        // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
        // Could not unmarshal file content test.json: parsing time "\"2022-09-26T21:00:00\\u002b00:00\"" as "\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"": cannot parse "\\u002b00:00\"" as "Z07:00"
        t.Fatalf("Could not unmarshal file content %s: %v", fileName, unmarshalErr)
    }
    for index, instance := range slice {
        if instance.Foo.Unix() != expectedStruct.Foo.Unix() {
            t.Fatalf("Unmarshalling failed for index %v in file %s. Expected %v but got %v", index, fileName, expectedStruct.Foo, instance.Foo)
        }
    }
}
```

It fails because of the escaped '+'.

> parsing time ""2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse "\u002b00:00"" as "Z07:00"

**Question**: Why does unmarshalling the time.Time field fail when it's being read from a file but works when the same json is read from an identical string?

Comment: In your source your string is within double quotes so is an [interpreted string literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals). The Go compiler will process the backslash escapes for you (try using back quotes instead of double quotes and you will get the same result as when you read from the file).

Comment: Brits is right: Using ``{"foo": "2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00"}`` in backticks instead of double quotes reproduces the problem without using a file. Still the behaviour of json.Unmarshal is unexpected to me. I think in the JSON standard it's allowed to escape characters?

Comment: Yep it's a known issue (see my comment on the answer).

Answer (score 5):

I believe that this is a bug in `encoding/json`.

Both the JSON grammar at https://www.json.org and the IETF definition of JSON at [RFC 8259, Section 7: Strings](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-7) provide that a JSON string may contain Unicode escape sequences:

> **7. Strings**
>
> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
> family of programming languages. A string begins and ends with quotation
> marks. All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks,
> except for the characters that MUST be escaped: quotation mark, reverse
> solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).
>
> Any character may be escaped. If the character is in the Basic
> Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a
> six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed by the lowercase letter
> u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the character's code
> point. The hexadecimal letters A through F can be uppercase or lowercase.
> So, for example, a string containing only a single reverse solidus
> character may be represented as "\u005C".
>
> . . .
>
> To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual
> Plane, the character is represented as a 12-character sequence, encoding
> the UTF-16 surrogate pair. So, for example, a string containing only the
> G-clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as "\uD834\uDD1E".
>
> ```
> string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
>
> char = unescaped /
>        escape (
>           %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
>           %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
>           %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
>           %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
>           %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
>           %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
>           %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
>           %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
>           %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
>
> escape = %x5C              ; \
>
> quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
>
> unescaped = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-10FFFF
> ```

The JSON document from the original post

```json
{
  "foo": "2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00"
}
```

Parses and deserializes perfectly fine in Node.js using `JSON.parse()`.

Here's an example demonstrating the bug:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var document []byte = []byte(`
{
  "value": "2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00"
}
`)

func main() {

    deserializeJsonAsTime()

    deserializeJsonAsString()

}

func deserializeJsonAsTime() {
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Println("Deserializing JSON as time.Time ...")

    type Widget struct {
        Value time.Time `json: "value"`
    }

    expected := Widget{
        Value: time.Date(2022, 9, 26, 21, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC),
    }
    actual := Widget{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(document, &actual)

    switch {
    case err != nil:
        fmt.Println("Error deserializing JSON as time.Time")
        fmt.Println(err)
    case actual.Value != expected.Value:
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshalling failed: expected %v but got %v\n", expected.Value, actual.Value)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Sucess")
    }

}

func deserializeJsonAsString() {
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Println("Deserializing JSON as string ...")

    type Widget struct {
        Value string `json: "value"`
    }

    expected := Widget{
        Value: "2022-09-26T21:00:00+00:00",
    }
    actual := Widget{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(document, &actual)

    switch {
    case err != nil:
        fmt.Println("Error deserializing JSON as string")
        fmt.Println(err)
    case actual.Value != expected.Value:
        fmt.Printf("Unmarshalling failed: expected %v but got %v\n", expected.Value, actual.Value)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Sucess")
    }

}
```

When run — see https://goplay.tools/snippet/fHQQVJ8GfPp — we get:

```
Deserializing JSON as time.Time ...
Error deserializing JSON as time.Time
parsing time "\"2022-09-26T21:00:00\\u002b00:00\"" as "\"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00\"": cannot parse "\\u002b00:00\"" as "Z07:00"

Deserializing JSON as string ...
Sucess
```

Since deserializing a JSON string containing Unicode escape sequences as a `string` yields the correct/expected result — the escape sequence being turned into the expected rune/byte sequence — the problem seemingly lies in the code that handles the deserialization to `time.Time` (It does not appear to deserialize to a string and then parse the string value as a `time.Time`.

Comment: Interesting - looks like there is [an existing issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47353) covering this.

Answer (score 0):

As [Brits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11810946/brits) point out this is one issue [time: UnmarshalJSON does not respect escaped unicode characters](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47353). We could solve those two errors when `json.Unmarshal` to the string `{"value": "2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00"}` in this way.

- `JSON fails when escaping '+' as '\u002b'`

  - Solution: Converting escaped unicode to utf8 through `strconv.Unquote`
- `cannot parse "\\u002b00:00\"" as "Z07:00"`

  - Solution: parse time with this format `"2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00"`

    - [`stdNumColonTZ  // "-07:00"`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/format.go#L157) from `src/time/format.go`
    - If you want to parse TimeZone from it, `time.ParseInLocation` could be used.

---

In order to make it compatible with `json.Unmarshal`, we could define one new type `utf8Time`

```golang
type utf8Time struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t *utf8Time) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    str, err := strconv.Unquote(string(data))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    tmpT, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00", str)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *t = utf8Time{tmpT}
    return nil
}

func (t utf8Time) String() string {
    return t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST")
}
```

Then to do the `json.Unmarshal`

```golang
type MyDoc struct {
    Value utf8Time `json:"value"`
}

var document = []byte(`{"value": "2022-09-26T21:00:00\u002b00:00"}`)

func main() {
    var mydoc MyDoc
    err := json.Unmarshal(document, &mydoc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(mydoc.Value)
}
```

Output

```
2022-09-26 21:00:00 +0000 +0000
```